# A method to draw a surface around a set of regularly spaced points

Tags: plotting, generative-art

This is mostly an artistic endeavour.

I have a 3D array of points, 1 representing a point within the surface, -1 without. The shape is not convex. I would like to produce a surface which encloses the points. One simple way is ListContourPlot:
[image: The contour between -1's and 1's in my data]

The surface is not very pleasing though; it is similar to the result of simply building the shape out of cubes without using any interpolation. Perhaps as a result of this, it is also very large, taking up 2gb of RAM.

What is a better way of doing this?

[Here is a subset of my data in .MAT format](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p8ixoowy0zu2c0g/sample_data.mat?dl=0).

Comment: Oh, I literally posted the same question just a few minutes ago. I am stuck with `ListContourPlot3D` right now, but there might be some options I do not know of for different "intepolation" methods.

Comment: What if you use `ListSurfacePlot3D[]` instead?

Comment: Without additional options, ListSurfacePlot3D[] produces almost identical results, and I cannot see any options which might improve this.

Comment: http://www.research.ibm.com/vistechnology/pdf/bpa_tvcg.pdf

Comment: Actually I believe this paper is more relevant: Lempitsky, "[Surface Extraction from Binary Volumes with Higher-Order Smoothness](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vilem/cvpr2010b.pdf)" (2010). That said, I got a nice-looking plot from your sample data by doing `ListContourPlot3D[Downsample[GaussianFilter[data, 5], 2], 
 Contours -> {0}]`.

Comment: user5751 and @Wizard: Are you two in the same class or so?

Comment: I sure hope not. I'm trying to whip up some fancy graphics for a grant.

Comment: Is the binary data all you have? If it was, for example, created by binarizing a continuous scalar field, you would get better results by running `ListContourPlot3D` on the pre-binarized data.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Definitely not, I think we are both past attending university lectures :).

Comment: @Rahul: I am aware of the paper, but am currently just interested in "onboard methods" supplied by mathematica directly. I also do think that the results from the paper tend to "oversmoothing", but it might be still one of the better techniques out there to use in my case.

Comment: @Rahul The binary data points take some (variable) time to produce. The data set is obtained from computations done on a cluster.

The idea is good, but I don't feel like I can make any good predictions about how many evaluations Mathematica is likely to ask for, and if we're talking about a job taking a day or a month.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the algorithm in the paper I linked to in a comment, "[Surface Extraction from Binary Volumes with Higher-Order Smoothness](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vilem/cvpr2010b.pdf)" by Lempitsky (2010), turned out to be pretty easy to implement (though for speed I changed eq. (10a) to a difference of Gaussians). And it works much better than my attempt, so I'm replacing that with this.

Build a signed distance field (SDF):

```
dOut = ImageClip[
   ImageSubtract[DistanceTransform[Image3D[-data]], 0.5], {0, 1*^6}];
dIn = ImageClip[
   ImageSubtract[DistanceTransform[Image3D[data]], 0.5], {0, 1*^6}];
sdf = ImageSubtract[dOut, dIn];
```

Define lower and upper bounds for the smoothed SDF:

```
l = ImageApply[Which[# >= 0, Max[# - 1, 0], True, -1*^6] &, sdf];
u = ImageApply[Which[# <= 0, Min[# + 1, 0], True, 1*^6] &, sdf];
```

Define the filtering operation:

```
filter[r_][sdf_] := 
 ImageApply[
  Clip[#1, {#2, #3}] &, {ImageSubtract[
    ImageMultiply[GaussianFilter[sdf, r], 4/3], 
    ImageMultiply[GaussianFilter[sdf, 2 r], 1/3]], l, u}]
```

And that's it!

If you don't have much time, use a large radius and a handful of iterations. Otherwise, use a small radius and a large number of iterations for higher-quality results.

```
draw[sdf_] := 
 ListContourPlot3D[ImageData[sdf], Contours -> {0}, 
  ContourStyle -> White, Mesh -> None]
draw[sdf]
Print[draw[filter[4][sdf]]]; // Timing
Print[draw[Nest[filter[2], sdf, 10]]]; // Timing
Print[draw[Nest[filter[1.2], sdf, 100]]]; // Timing
```

[image]

[image]

```
(* {6.74007, Null} *)
```

[image]

```
(* {39.5372, Null} *)
```

[image]

```
(* {365.001, Null} *)
```

Comment: @Rahul Your previous solution using a GaussianFilter has produced quite excellent results, although it is a touch slow. I'd like to accept it as an answer but it's just a comment.

Comment: @user5751: The reason I didn't recommend `GaussianFilter` in my answer is that it can completely lose narrow features: http://i.stack.imgur.com/S9M8m.png becomes http://i.stack.imgur.com/zCmLW.png

Comment: @user5751: See my update (though it's even slower than a plain old `GaussianFilter`).

Comment: I dunno, sometimes one just has to spend more time in exchange for higher quality. It's too bad I can't upvote again.