# Smooth curves in a raster image

Tags: image-processing, data-acquisition, smoothing

I have a *.bmp image, e.g. this one:

[image]

I need to smooth boundaries of the thick curves and save it in a vector graphics form. Is there a simple way how to do that in Mathematica 10? I know it is probably an easy task, but can't figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: "save it in a vector graphics form" - `ImageMesh[ColorNegate[image]]` would be a good start.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I have a version 10.

Comment: What is about horizontal thick black lines? Should they be kept or removed?

Comment: They should be kept.

Comment: As I understand, your image is a rasterized contour plot, and you wish to preserve sharp corners where the horizontal lines intersect with the curves. Is it correct?

Comment: It is actually Binarized@ArrayPlot + 2 horizontal lines. You are right, I would like to have curves with smooth boundaries and the lines across them, with sharp corners in intersection.

Comment: Without such a requirement I would suggest double `Blur` as the first step: `Binarize[Blur[Blur[i, 6], 6], .5]`. That would be easy but with the additional requirement the problem becomes tricky.

Comment: It's a good idea, the horizontal lines don't matter, I could make them right later on. But what I need is to have these curves with really smooth and sharp edges and export them in a vector graphics format so that it is easily resizeable in external programs, without loss of quality. And I'm not sure that this is the right way how to do that.

Comment: Have you seen https://vectormagic.com ?

Comment: It's wonderful, but a bit expensive. But this is exactly what I need to do.

Comment: Maybe like a 2D version of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97548/484)?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to have curves with smooth boundaries and the lines across them, with sharp corners in intersection.

### Part 1: isolate the boundaries

Import the image and remove the frame:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJwTu.png"];
img1 = ImagePad[img, -4]
```

> [image: output]

Remove the white borders excepting the left border (we'll need it at the next steps):

```
border = BorderDimensions[ImageTake[img1, 20]];
img2 = ImagePad[img1, -border + {{4, 0}, {0, 0}}]
```

> [image: output]

Find positions of the pixels of the horizontal lines and make them white:

```
horizontalLinesPos = {All, #2} & @@@ PixelValuePositions[ImageTake[img2, All, 1], 0];
img3 = ReplacePixelValue[img2, horizontalLinesPos -> 1]
```

> [image: output]

Find internal perimeters of the black components:

```
img4 = MorphologicalTransform[ColorNegate@img3, "Remove"]
```

> [image: output]

At this step we get a problem. We have to decide what to do with the horizontal "tails" like this:

```
ArrayPlot[1 - ImageData[ImageTake[img4, {51, 67}, {334, 351}]], Mesh -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

> [image: output]

Since such "tails" correspond to actual data points (represented as black pixels on the original image), it is reasonable to keep them.

Now we have to remove the horizontal and vertical borders excepting at the left where the vertical border actually is a continuation of the curve. And we have to keep the "tails" at the same time. For this purpose it is better to start again from the `img2`:

```
img3 = MorphologicalTransform[ColorNegate@img2, "Remove", Padding -> 1];
img4 = ReplacePixelValue[img3, horizontalLinesPos -> 0]
```

> [image: output]

### Part 2: extract the curves

```
masks = ComponentMeasurements[img4, "Mask"];

curves = Transpose[Reverse@#]["NonzeroPositions"] & /@ masks[[;; , 2]];

horLines = Join[{∞}, Mean /@ Split[horizontalLinesPos[[;; , 2]], Abs[#1 - #2] == 1 &], {0}]
```

> ```
> {∞, 508, 342, 175, 0}
> ```

```
dataLines = 
  DeleteCases[
   Flatten[#, 1] & /@ 
    Transpose[PadRight[
      Table[Select[curves, horLines[[i]] > Min[#[[;; , 2]]] > horLines[[i + 1]] &], 
        {i, Length[horLines] - 1}], Automatic, Missing[]]], {Missing[], Missing[]}, {2}];

ListPlot[dataLines]
```

> [image: listplot]

### Part 3: smooth the curves

There are infinitely many possible ways to perform the smoothing. For recovering the original data points the approach shown by [nikie](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/242/nikie) in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/90131/280) answer seems the most appropriate. If the goal is just to obtain smoothed boundaries, one can use approaches shown in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144342/280) thread.

Answer (score 1):

The smoothing of the edges can be accomplished using one of the edge-preserving smoothing functions. For example, the PeronaMakil filter gives:

```
img = ImagePad[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJwTu.png"], -4];
edges = EdgeDetect[PeronaMalikFilter[img, 20, 100]]
```

[image]

Another similar filter is the `CurvatureFlowFilter`.