# How to get a smooth outline

Tags: image-processing, smoothing

I have a outline image

```
img=Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
    Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc0Mt.png"],"Byte"]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is current method

```
pos = ImageValuePositions[img, 1];
newPos = Nest[Function[pts, Mean@*Rest /@ Nearest[pts, pts, 3]], pos, 50];
ReplaceImageValue[ConstantImage[0, ImageDimensions[img]], newPos -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And I don't know how to connect those pixels

```
Graphics[Line /@ Nearest[newPos, newPos, 3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are two question in this code

- I's very slow for a big picture
- Hard to get a connected picture

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`CurvatureFlowFilter` is great for smoothing binary images.

```
img = Uncompress[
  FromCharacterCode[
   Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNRoa.png"], 
     "Byte"]]]];
filled = Colorize[
  WatershedComponents[Dilation[img, 1], CornerNeighbors -> False], 
  ColorRules -> {1 -> White, 2 -> White, 3 -> White, 
    4 -> White, _ -> Black}];
MorphologicalPerimeter@
 Binarize@CurvatureFlowFilter[Binarize@filled, 10]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting results can also be obtained by directly doing `Erosion[CurvatureFlowFilter[Dilation[img, 1], 10], 1]`.

Comment: Wow,good solution, and easily to understand.Thanks very much..

Comment: Or replace Rahul's CurvatureFlowFilter with `PeronaMalikFilter[Binarize@filled, 10, 30]`

Comment: @bills: Can you say something about the difference between `CurvatureFlowFilter` and `PeronaMalikFilter`?

Comment: Rahul -- they both attack the same problem (smoothing of curves) in a similar way (by solving a differential equation). The difference is in the specific DEs chosen and in the properties of that DE. From an implementation perspective, I would suggest trying them both.

Comment: @bills: I know that they are different, I was hoping you could say something about *how* they are different and/or in what circumstances you might prefer one over the other. My understanding is that on *binary* images, `CurvatureFlowFilter` is always more appropriate and gives reliably better results than `PeronaMalikFilter`. I'd be grateful to see an example of a binary image where `PeronaMalikFilter` performs better, so that I can revise my understanding.

Comment: @bills Still waiting for an example of a binary image on which `PeronaMalikFilter` does better than `CurvatureFlowFilter` (in whatever sense you had in mind).

Answer (score 4):

### `Blur` & `Binarize`

One way is to `Blur` and then `Binarize` with threshold **exactly** `0.5` (no need to adjust!):

```
MorphologicalTransform[Binarize[Blur[FillingTransform[Closing[img, 1]], 5], 0.5], "Remove"]
```

> [image: output]

(In some cases (but not in this case) applying `Blur` *twice* can give better results:

```
MorphologicalTransform[
 Binarize[Blur[Blur[FillingTransform[Closing[img, 1]], 3], 4], .5], "Remove"]
```

)

If further smoothing is needed, one can apply this method separately to each component of the image using one of the methods from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144395/280) thread:

```
i = Closing[img, 1];
cm = ComponentMeasurements[{MorphologicalComponents[i], ColorNegate@i}, {"MaskedImage", 
    "BoundingBox"}];

smoothComponent[img_, n_] := 
  ImagePad[MorphologicalTransform[
    Binarize[Blur[ImagePad[FillingTransform[ColorNegate@img], n], n], 0.5], "Remove"], -n];

smoothAllComponents[cm_, n_] := Module[{newComps, iW, iH},
   newComps = smoothComponent[#, n] & /@ cm[[;; , 2, 1]];
   {iW, iH} = ImageDimensions@i;
   Image[Total[
     Table[SparseArray[
       Band[1 + Round@{iH - #[[2, 2]], #[[1, 1]]} &@cm[[i, 2, 2]]] -> 
        ImageData[newComps[[i]]], {iH, iW}], {i, Length[cm]}]]]];

Table[s[cm, n], {n, 20}]
```

> [image: output]

---

### `Dilation` & `Thinning`

```
cm = ComponentMeasurements[img, "Image"];

Table[ColorNegate@ImagePad[Thinning[Dilation[ImagePad[cm[[2, 2]], r], r]], -r], {r, 1, 
  4, .5}]
```

> [image: output]

Applying to each of the components individually:

```
i = Closing[img, 1];
cm = ComponentMeasurements[{MorphologicalComponents[i], ColorNegate@i}, {"MaskedImage", 
    "BoundingBox"}];

smoothComponent[img_, r_] := ImagePad[Thinning[Dilation[ImagePad[img, r], r]], -r];

smoothAllComponents[cm_, n_] := Module[{newComps, iW, iH},
   newComps = smoothComponent[#, n] & /@ cm[[;; , 2, 1]];
   {iW, iH} = ImageDimensions@i;
   Image[Total[
     Table[SparseArray[
       Band[1 + Round@{iH - #[[2, 2]], #[[1, 1]]} &@cm[[i, 2, 2]]] -> 
        ImageData[newComps[[i]]], {iH, iW}], {i, Length[cm]}]]]];

Table[s[cm, n], {n, 20}]
```

> [image: output]

It is easy to check that the output is identical to the one obtained in the previous section.

Comment: I guess, the best way to have a principally smooth contours is usage of `MorphologicalComponents` for separation of separated contours and following interpolation of their points after re-ordering as sequence from one to the nearest.. But Alexey's method is much easy :)

Comment: I always avoid to use those `threshold value` in a real solution too much,it will make the code be in low applicability.Anyway,thanks for show the `Blur+Binarize`. :)

Comment: @yode In this particular application the threshold `0.5` is **fixed** and hence you don't have to adjust it!

Comment: @yode I updated my answer with another method.

Comment: @Rahul Probably not. I can't reproduce my results using only `Closing`. If you can, please post an answer.

Comment: +1).Thanks again,but the new method just can process one component one time?Well,I feel guilty,it's seem I always have some further request.

Comment: @yode Yes, one component on time. But it could be automatized.

Comment: @yode Actually the first method also must be restricted to one component if you need further smoothing...

Comment: I have reduced the requirement,if you have seen the [old version](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/144342/1) of this post,It has many components.I afraid it too hard to request an answer,so I have simplified it.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, here's Simon Woods' approach from [How to create a new "person curve"?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/how-to-create-a-new-person-curve/17780#17780)

```
param[x_, m_, t_] := 
  Module[{f, n = Length[x], nf}, 
   f = Chop[Fourier[x]][[;; Ceiling[Length[x]/2]]];
   nf = Length[f];
   Total[(2 Abs[f]/Sqrt[n] Sin[
        Pi/2 - Arg[f] + 2. Pi Range[0, nf - 1] t])[[;; Min[m, nf]]]]];

tocurve[Line[data_], m_, t_] := param[#, m, t] & /@ Transpose[data];
```

OP's example:

```
img = Uncompress[
   FromCharacterCode[
    Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc0Mt.png"], 
      "Byte"]]], HoldComplete];    
img = ReleaseHold@img

pts0 = PixelValuePositions[img, 1];
paths = FindCurvePath@pts0;
pts = pts0[[#]] & /@ paths;
pp = MapThread[ (* parametrized paths *)
   tocurve[Line[#1], #2, t] &,
   {pts,
    Max[#, 4] & /@ Round[(Length /@ pts)/12] (* no. of modes - controls smoothing *)}
   ];
pp = pp - (pp /. _Sin -> 0) + (Mean /@ pts);
plot = ParametricPlot[pp, {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]
Show[img, plot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]    
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another example (from original question):

```
img0 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/myVKd.png"];
img2 = Thinning@Binarize[img0, 0.05]

pts0 = PixelValuePositions[img2, 1];
paths = Rest@FindCurvePath@pts0; (* remove boundary *)
pts = pts0[[#]] & /@ paths;
pp = MapThread[ (* parametrized paths *)
   tocurve[Line[#1], #2, t] &,
   {pts,
    Max[#, 4] & /@ Round[(Length /@ pts)/12](* no. of modes - controls smoothing *)}
   ];
pp = pp - (pp /. _Sin -> 0) + (Mean /@ pts);
plot = ParametricPlot[pp, {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]
Show[img2, plot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Method1:

```
meshes = 
ConnectedMeshComponents@
ImageMesh@
CurvatureFlowFilter[FillingTransform@Dilation[img, 1], 10];
Graphics[
BSplineCurve[MeshPrimitives[#, 0][[All, 1]], 
SplineClosed -> True] & /@ meshes]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect,but almost.I solve the *disconnected* problem in original post and it is slow still..

```
img = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
   Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc0Mt.png"],"Byte"]]]]

findMeanPoint[pos_] := 
 Module[{firstPoint, pairDir, secondPoint}, 
  firstPoint = Nearest[pos, pos, 2];
  pairDir = 
   Dispatch[Thread[pos -> Normalize@*Subtract @@@ firstPoint]];
  secondPoint = 
   Last /@ Nearest[pos, pos, 2, 
     DistanceFunction -> (If[Equal@##, 0, 
         Rescale[Abs[VectorAngle[#1 /. pairDir, #2 - #1]], {0, 
            Pi}, {.1, 2}]*EuclideanDistance[##]] &)];
  MapThread[Mean@*Prepend, {firstPoint, secondPoint}]]
newPos = Nest[findMeanPoint, ImageValuePositions[Thinning[img], 1], 
   40];

DeleteSmallComponents[
 ReplaceImageValue[ConstantImage[0, ImageDimensions[img]],newPos -> 1], 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]