# How to get an image skeleton sharp with long lines

Tags: image-processing

How can I get a straight skeleton of an image.

1@ just use vertical, horizontal lines in situation of image1.
2@ include tilted lines in situation of image2.

[image]

Background, using least lines to reconstruct the window flower.
The question is something like getting a good wireframe of a 3d model,
I want to construct such a wireframe 3d model from the image.

[image]

[How to get a smooth outline](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144342/6648)

[image]